# React Native Doesn`t re-render after context state change

Tags: react-native, react-hooks

state changes after getting data from api. i can see that with console.log()

but doesn`t render data after update. there is my code fetch code :

```
useEffect(() =>  {
   
      axios
      .get(
      'https://mylink.ngrok.io/channels/getUser',
      ).then((data)=>{
        let array = [];
    const promises =  data.data.channels.map((channel)=>{
         axios.get(`https://mylink.ngrok.io/channels/getChannel/${channel}`).then((resp)=>{
          array.push(resp.data);
         })
        
       })
         Promise.all(promises).then(()=>{
          setonLineChannels(array);
        });
      
      })
    
    
    
  }, []);
```

btw its in context.

I think  Promise.all casue of that

thx

Comment: Thx it worked! u can publish this answer bro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where you declare `promises`, it's not going to wait for those API requests to complete. They're running even before you've called `Promise.all(promises)`.

You can just put the code you've defined as `promises` inside the `Promise.all()` directly, then make sure you return the get request inside. And don't push to `array`. Your map will return an array of promises, and you can use the results array in the `.then` after `Promise.all` to update your state directly.

Here's what I mean:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  axios.get("https://mylink.ngrok.io/channels/getUser").then((data) => {
    Promise.all(
      data.data.channels.map(
        (channel) =>
          axios
            .get(`https://mylink.ngrok.io/channels/getChannel/${channel}`)
            .catch((err) => console.error(err)) // this allows an individual request to fail
      )
    ).then((results) => setonLineChannels(results));
  });
}, []);
```